# At a high zoom feature icons disappear

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

When zoomed into a feature icon, the larger scale it is the more chance it has of not being displayed when partially off screen.

The geom point is center of the icon, so at a high zoom the geom point being off screen put it outside of the extent (fine), but I need the icon to still display partially within the extent.  The effect is that it stays partially onscreen until it hits just past half way off screen at which point it stops displaying.

I've looked at ol.extent.buffer but I don't think it's for me.  Is there a 'buffer ' I can set that means that the view is rendering an extent larger than it so icons will still display partially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ol.layer.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html?unstable=true) takes a `renderBuffer` argument, which lets you specify a buffer around the viewport which will be included in the rendering. The default is 100px.

Comment: That worked.  I did come across that in the docs, but was unclear what it did.  Still have the issue of; as I'm using 'scale' to size the images of the vector I don't know their lengths well enough to derive a pixel value, I've put a sufficiently larger number in there to mostly fix this issue.